# Linux, serial port, non-buffering mode

Tags: linux, serial-port, nonblocking, unbuffered

I am trying to organize nob-blocking read-write functionality with serial port in Linux. Here is the code I have: http://pastebin.com/RSPw7HAi
It all works fine, but it is buffered. That means, that if I do input to serial via console + CR symbol, select detects new input, otherwise, if I do input via simple python script, it buffers all symbols and waits until I send it carriage return symbol.
So with this input (given below) it simply buffers symbols somewhere.
I have to PCs connected via USB2Serial converter

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import serial

cmd1_state = b'\x3E\x01\x00\x01'

#Selecting serial port for commands to be sent --> /dev/ttyUSB0
serial_0 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB2');
print("Using serial port ", serial_0.portstr);
serial_0.write(cmd1_state)

# closing serial port
serial_0.close()
```

So, can anybody tell me what to do here? Do I have to change something within port opening in my C file or it's to be done with python script? I used flush() method in later, but it also did not help.
BTW, I've googled out about F_NOCACHE arg to fcntl() function. BUT! It's all about BSD and Darwin OS's, there is no such thing (F_NOACHE arg to fcntl) in Linux, as far as I could see.

UPD:
Looks like I found out the solution.

```
 /* set input mode (non-canonical, no echo,...) */
newtio.c_lflag = 0;

newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;   /* inter-character timer unused */
newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 1;   /* blocking read until 1 char received */

tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
```

Taken from : http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer and accept it so that this question doesn't show up as unanswered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I found out the solution.

```
/* set input mode (non-canonical, no echo,...) */
newtio.c_lflag = 0;

newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;   /* inter-character timer unused */
newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 1;   /* blocking read until 1 char received */

tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
Taken from : http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html
```

Comment: A better (i.e. portable) guide is [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).  Also see [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)